# python modified printing function

Tags: python

I made 5 lists which represents tokens (lexical classes) - identifiers, constants, operators, keywords and separators.

Reading from .txt file, I'm sorting file elements into my lists.

My .txt file

```
a273 = 4 + 1337
variable = 50.123132123 + 3.123123132 / 23.121212
```

a273 is appended into identifiers, ' ' and '\n' into separators, = into operators, 4 and 1337 into constants and + in operators. (same for the next line)

So I want to make a some kind of modified print function which will print my elements like this:

```
('a273', identifiers)
(' ', separators)
('=', operators)
(' ', separators)
('4', constants)
(' ', separators)
('+', operators)
(' ', separators)
('1337', constants)
```

And print like that for all lines.

I tried something like this (for identifiers only)

```
for i in newList:
       if i in identifiers:
           print(i, " identifiers")
```

but I get multiple same identifiers printed.

this is my code for sorting separators, identifiers and constants

```
lexicalClass = file.readlines()

for lex in lexicalClass:

    if len(re.findall('\s+', lex)):
            separators.extend(re.findall('\s+', lex))
        
a_string = lex.split()
for word in a_string:
     if len(re.findall(r"\b(?!S+)[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]? 
     \d+)?\b(?!S+)", word)):
        constants.extend(re.findall(r"\b(?!S+)[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+) 
        (?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?\b(?!S+)", word))

newList = re.findall('\S+', lex)
for element in newList:
    if len(re.findall('[a-z]+[0-9]+|[a-z]+', element)):
        identifiers.extend(re.findall('[a-z]+[0-9]+|[a-z]+', element))
```

EDIT:

I added this code:

```
tokens = identifiers.copy()
tokens.extend(operators)
tokens.extend(separators)
tokens.extend(keywords)
tokens.extend(constants)  

for i in range(len(lexicalClass) - 1):
    print(f'Line {i}: ')
    for element in tokens:
        if element in operators:
            print({element}, 'operators')
        elif element in identifiers:
            print({element}, 'identifers')
        elif element in separators:
            print({element}, 'identifers')
    print("\n")
```

But im getting this output

```
Line 0: 
{'a273'} identifers
{'i'} identifers
{'aifj'} identifers
{'variable'} identifers
{'+'} operators
{'+'} operators
{'++'} operators
{'/'} operators
{'='} operators
{'='} operators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{'\n'} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{'\n'} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{'\n'} separators

Line 1: 
{'a273'} identifers
{'i'} identifers
{'aifj'} identifers
{'variable'} identifers
{'+'} operators
{'+'} operators
{'++'} operators
{'/'} operators
{'='} operators
{'='} operators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{'\n'} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{'\n'} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{' '} separators
{'\n'} separators
```

I want to print line by line and its element, but im getting in every line whole file printed and also elements are not sorted (all identifiers are printed first, then operators...)

Comment: could you share some more of your code? for example, that is the newList or identifiers variable?

Comment: Added code for identifiers, constants and separators

Comment: Hey @MarkoMarkusevic, just a small piece of advice when posting your code. Don't add newlines to fit the code horizontally. Simply leave it to spill over, and there will be a horizontal scroll bar on the bottom, and it will be easily copied for someone to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `set` concept in python.

```
s = set(newList)
for i in s:
       if i in identifiers:
           print(i, " identifiers")
```

Here, all the unique elements of your list will be added to set. So this, will remove your duplicate values which was coming in your output.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach is to parse the line "word" by "word" and print while you go. You currently parse the whole line at once with one regex. Instead, use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split the line to all its tokens and then parse each:

```py
import re

s = """a273 = 4 + 1337
variable = 50.123132123 + 3.123123132 / 23.121212"""

separators = []
constants = []
operators = []
identifiers = []

for line in s.splitlines():
    for token in re.split(r"(\s+)", line):
        if re.match(r"\s+$", token):
            separators.append(token)
            kind = "separator"
        elif re.match(r"\d+(.\d+)?$", token):
            constants.append(token)
            kind = "constant"
        elif re.match(r"[a-z]+([0-9]+)?$", token):
            identifiers.append(token)
            kind = "identifier"
        elif re.match(r"[=+/*-]$", token):
            operators.append(token)
            kind = "operator"
        else:
            kind = None

        print(f"({token}, {kind})")
```

This will print:

```
('a273', identifier)
(' ', separator)
('=', operator)
(' ', separator)
('4', constant)
(' ', separator)
('+', operator)
(' ', separator)
('1337', constant)
('variable', identifier)
(' ', separator)
('=', operator)
(' ', separator)
('50.123132123', constant)
(' ', separator)
('+', operator)
(' ', separator)
('3.123123132', constant)
(' ', separator)
('/', operator)
(' ', separator)
('23.121212', constant)
```

And you will also have the lists filled at the end of the run. For example:

```
>>> print(constants)
['4', '1337', '50.123132123', '3.123123132', '23.121212']
```